# Оперетка или опереттка?

Tags: орфография

Вообще-то, она — опереТТа. Но, когда зашла речь о маленьком произведении, почему-то было написано через одно Т: оперетка. Правильно ли это и, если да, то куда делось второе Т?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Розенталь:

В словах, образованных от основ, оканчивающихся на две одинаковые согласные, двойные согласные перед суффиксом **сохраняются**, например: балл — пятибалльный, галл — галльский, гунн — гуннский, компромисс — компромиссный, группа — группка, диаграмма — диаграммка, программа — программка, телеграмма — телеграммка. То же — в собственных именах, например: Канберрский университет, Каннский кинофестиваль, Лозаннская конференция, боннское правительство, таллиннские памятники старины и т. п.

**Исключения**. В некоторых словах в рассматриваемом случае пишется одна согласная, например: кристалл — кристальный, финн — финский, колонна — колонка, тонна — пятитонка, финн — финка (обычно двойное н стягивается в одно н перед суффиксом — к-а), оперетта — **оперетка;** в названиях лиц с суффиксом — к, например: Алла — Алка, Анна — Анка, Кирилл — Кирилка, Римма — Римка, Савва — Савка, Филипп — Филипка, Эмма — Эмка.

Answer (score 1):

Пишется "опереТка" с одной Т. Вторая Т выпадает из-за еще одной присоединяющейся согласной (суффикс К), чтобы не получилось излишнего скопления согласных. В словах "кристалл" - "кристальный" и др. также. 
    Но на самом деле все намного сложнее. См. http://www.rusyaz.ru/pr/os02.html ($69)